# Join Folder Path to File Name from .csv Import

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I am trying to write a program that will take in a CSV file containing 1 column of file names, append a source,then destination file path, then move those select files to the destination folder.
Csv example:

```
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg
etc...
```

I have tried several different versions of solutions found on this site, but they all have the same error for me:

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Here is my most recent code:

```py
import csv
import shutil

#  Test path variables
source_folder = "/Users/user/Desktop/testSource/"
destination_folder = "/Users/user/Desktop/testDest/"
list_path = "/Users/user/Desktop/"
list_file = "test.csv"
list_name = list_path + list_file
print("Importing from file: ",list_name)

#  Opens the.csv and saves result to a list
with (open(list_name, 'r') as csvfile):
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    file_names = list(reader)
    print("I found these entries: ",file_names)
    source_files = [source_folder + i for i in file_names]
    print(source_files)
```

This is where the error occurs, despite several iterations. I cannot join elements from the list, nor split the list into discrete elements. Python seems to think file_names both is and is not a list. If I can get the source append part working I can duplicate for destination, and build my complete lists of paths to iterate through.

Any help would be appreciated, I have no idea what I'm missing.

Tried to join source/destination file paths to each element in a list, expecting full path names to hand off to shutil.

I continually get `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` error.

Comment: There's no good reason to treat your input file as a CSV if it always contains just one column. Just read the file line-by-line and treat each line as a file name (after stripping the newline character).

Comment: I had not considered that. A CSV was the first option that came to mind as it's simple to export from excel which was already part of my workflow. Sounds like a good learning opportunity to expand functionality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your CSV only has one column, the csv.reader thinks of a "row" as a list of strings.

If you print your `file_names` variable, you'll see mutlipe rows (a list of list of strings):

```py
[
    ['img1.jpg'],
    ['img2.jpg'],
    ['img3.jpg'],
]
```

Your list comprehension `[... for i in file_names]` is only iterating at the row level, `i` is still a list of strings, so you're effectively trying to concatenate a string and a list (of strings).  Figuartively that looks something like:

```py
 source_folder + ['img1.jpg']
```

So Python gives us the sensible error,

```
Importing from file:  ./input.csv
I found these entries:  [['img1.jpg'], ['img2.jpg'], ['img3.jpg']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zyoung/develop/StackOverflow/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    source_files = [source_folder + i for i in file_names]
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

(and we can also see in the printout, "I found these entries", that we're dealing with a list of list of strings)

For your simple case, just indexing into the row to get the first (and only) field will solve the problem:

```py
[source_folder + i[0] for i in file_names]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My account is too new to give you reputation, but I appreciate it very much!!